# How to provide details/summary HTML element in TYPO3's CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

Unfortunately there's no details/summary element in the default CKEditor configuration of TYPO3 and I'm looking for a way to add it.

What I've been trying to do:

I searched and found a widget on https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/detail , but it's [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/akilli/ckeditor4-detail) has been archived and the widget does not work as expected. It requires `'api,widget'` and this generates a JavaScript error:
`[CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "api" was not found at "/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/plugins/api/plugin.js?t=K24B-4e13cc129f"`.
When removing this requirement for "api", there's an error regarding line 72
`CKEDITOR.api.parser.add(item, el);`.

Then I found a [similar widget at GitHub](https://github.com/Sensetivity/ckeditor4-detail) , which looks like an older version of the former without requirement for "api".
It already looks quite good, but is still a bit buggy: the HTML structure is changed when saving and the summary is duplicated. When switching to the source code, the HTML structure specified in the template ...
`<details><summary>Summary</summary><div class="details-content"></div></details>`
… get's partially lost.

I'm not sure if the widgets are buggy or if the editor is limited by the integration into TYPO3 and I was also not able to combine the two in a way that would lead to a working solution.

**Update (Jul 22):**
I successfully modified the [Creating a Simple CKEditor Widget (Part 1)](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1.html) example to create
a widget with the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="expander">
    <p class="expander-title">Title</p>
    <div class="expander-content"><p>Content...</p></div>
</div>
```

With the help of a small JavaScript snippet and some CSS it now behaves almost like a details-summary element, but is not quite as good in terms of SEO and accessibility.

If I replace the elements `<div class="expander">` and `<p class="expander-title">` with `<details>` and `<summary>` in the widget, it unfortunately doesn't work properly anymore and changes the structure when saving. For some reason the RTE treats them differently.

I have already manually added the following to the RTE configuration:

```
processing:
  allowTags:
    - details
    - summary
  allowTagsOutside:
    - details
    - summary
```

Comment: I don't the solution for your CKEditor problem, however maybe as a workaround, you can use **mask** extension for creating custom HTML editable elements.

Comment: A new content element unfortunately does not work in this case. In a previous project I did this before (without mask, but with an extension), but in this case the editors really need the element in the RTE. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hope that somebody will share the solution for CKE then